# Absolute path of cloudfront while displacing custom error pages

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-cloudfront

I have an application which reside on EC2 instance, traffic comes from cloudfront--->ALB---->EC2 instance. If anyone is access the wrong url, the application throw an error page depending on the error.

Suppose, if I type a wrong url (abc.com/test/index.html) it will redirect to abc.com/error/404 (This is manage through application itself).

If, EC2 instance is down the error page are display through cloudfront using custom error page. But the problem here is, when I type the wrong url (abc.com/test/index.html) it will display the error page of 404 but will not change the url to abc.com/error/404 .

Also, the error page display through S3 bucket. Can anyone suggest any option to set this up in cloudfront.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

Based on what you wrote, I suppose you're using ReactJS or similar since you're handling error pages in your application.

In order to do that in the ReactJS application, you need to add custom error responses for 403 and 404 codes.
For both of these, you need to set ResponseCode to 200 and ResponsePagePath to "/index.html" (since index.html is what's doing the routing in your application)